# Como impedir fuga de memoria al llamar funciones en C++

Tags: c++, memoria

Tengo una preocupación sobre el manejo de memoria en C++ porque creo que esta ocurriendo muchas fugas en mi código:

Les voy a poner un ejemplo muy sencillo para mostrar donde esta el problema:

```
#include<iostream>


int suma(int a, int b){
    //creo un puntero con memoria dinamica
    int* resultado = new int(a+b);
    return *resultado;
}

int main(){
    int sumados=suma(3434,234);
    std::cout << sumados << std::endl;

}
```

cada vez que llamo a suma se crea un objeto de memoria dinámica y como no lo estoy borrando con delete entonces se acumulan en la memoria.

Las soluciones que he encontrado en la web son muy complicadas y consisten en usar los llamados PUNTEROS INTELIGENTES pero no los comprendo como para integrarlos a mis códigos.

Si alguien puede explicarme a profundidad como se usan se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: 1- Estás pidiendo un tutorial, y ese tipo de preguntas no se ajustan al sitio. 2- En tú código usas memoria dinámica porque quieres, porque no hay necesidad de usarla para algo tan tirivial. No usarla garantiza que no habrá fugas. 3- Las fugas son exclusivas de cada ejecución. Cuando tu programa termina, toda la memoria se libera. Toda. Las fugas no se van acumulando una ejecución tras otra.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a responder la pregunta con la solución más sencilla:

Solo veo dos posibles razones para que estés teniendo que hacer esto

1. Porque no entiendes el lenguaje.
2. Porque estás tratando de retornar un objeto(una estructura o algo así).

En cualquier caso tienes también dos opciones.

1. Si es posible no tener que retornar un puntero, pero necesitas un puntero antes de `return` simplemente copia a una variable local, libéralo y retorna la variable local. Algo así:

```cpp
#include<iostream>


int suma(int a, int b){
    //creo un puntero con memoria dinamica
    int* resultado = new int(a+b);
    int miVariableLocal = *resultado;
    delete resultado;
    return miVariableLocal;
}

int main(){
    int sumados=suma(3434,234);
    std::cout << sumados << std::endl;

}
```

2. Lee el valor retornado como puntero, úsalo y luego simplemente aplica `delete` en el como cualquier valor normal. Algo así:

```cpp
#include<iostream>


int *suma(int a, int b){
    //creo un puntero con memoria dinamica
    int* resultado = new int(a+b);
    return resultado;
}

int main(){
    int *sumados=suma(3434,234);
    std::cout << *sumados << std::endl;
    delete sumados;

}
```

No quieres complicarte con punteros inteligentes? Bien, ¿de verdad los necesitas?

Comment: Como una nota, en el segundo, no estas retornando el puntero, lo estas derefenciando. Tiene que ser `return resultado;`

Comment: Ah, gracias, me equivoqué, corregido

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el ejemplo que nos diste no es representativo de lo que quieres hacer, o lo que quieres hacer no tiene nada de sentido. Para que usar memoria dinámica si vas a retornar la variable por valor? El heap lo usas cuando los objetos son demasiado grandes para el stack, o cuando no sabes cual va a ser el tamaño de los objetos. En ninguno de los dos casos vas a retornar el objeto por valor, sino que lo vas a retornar por puntero:

```
#include<iostream>

int* suma(int a, int b) {
    int* resultado = new int(a+b);
    return resultado;
}

int main(){
    int* sumados = suma(3434, 234);
    std::cout << *sumados << std::endl;
    delete sumados;
    return 0;
}
```

Habiendo aclarado eso, lo que pides es que te expliquen como usar los punteros inteligentes. Estos siguen uno de los patrones de diseño mas útiles de C++, [RAII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), que es un acrónimo terrible, pero una idea que te ahorrara muchos problemas en el futuro. La verdad es que si los vas a trabajar de una forma tan sencilla, prácticamente no hay cambios:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

static std::unique_ptr<int> suma(int a, int b) {
    // A make_unique le pasas los argumentos que le pasarias a new
    std::unique_ptr<int> resultado = std::make_unique<int>(a + b);
    return resultado;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> sumados = suma(3434, 234);
    std::cout << *sumados << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tienes tu `std::unique_ptr`, y este va a liberar la memoria cada vez que **muevas** otro `std::unique_ptr` (o un `nullptr_t`) a el, y cuando se termine su tiempo de vida.

Aquí tienes mas información en el [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Como una nota, porque creo que es lo que esta pasando aquí. No tienes que usar partes del lenguaje que no necesitas. No hace tu código mejor, de hecho, en este caso solo hace el código infinitamente mas lento. Siempre ve primero a la solución mas sencilla.